# Active Directory profile pictures sync with

Tags: spservices, active-directory-import, 2019

How to import Active Directory profile pictures into SharePoint 2019?

SPMA EXPORT is not working. It shows stopped. Any help? 
[image]

Comment: Is there any extra detail you'd like to provide?  Other users might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to import pictures, you need to use MIM instead of Active Directory import. [Here is great article about it.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52444.sharepoint-server-2019-working-with-microsoft-identity-manager-2016-sp1.aspx)

Or you can use some PowerShell script for importing photos, [like here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/adamsorenson/2017/05/24/user-profile-picture-import-with-active-directory-import/).

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: You mean MIM?  SharePoint no longer brings along FIM for the ride.

Comment: yes MIM see in post

Comment: Cool.  Not trying to be pedantic, just accurate for future googlers.